# Can I pass "this" as a parameter to another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, this

I have this:

```
$('#slider li').click(function () {
    var stepClicked = $(this).index();
    alert(stepClicked);
    if (stepClicked != 0) {
        $('#cs_previous').removeClass('cs_hideMe');
    } else {
        $('#cs_previous').addClass('cs_hideMe');
    }

    $('li.cs_current').removeClass('cs_current');
    $($(this)).addClass('cs_current');


    moveToNextImage(stepClicked);

    function moveToNextImage(stepClicked) {
        alert(stepClicked);
        var currentIs = $('li.cs_current').index();
        var newLeftEdge = currentIs - stepClicked;
        $('.cs_riskStageImage').fadeTo(200, .2).animate({
            left: newLeftEdge
        }, "fast").fadeTo(200, 1);
    };
});
```

the alert shows the proper index for the li clicked, and when I alert the variable within the last function I'm calling, `moveToNextImage(stepClicked)`, the same value shows but the animation isn't happening. This works many other ways, but I'm trying to pass the index value of the list item clicked to use for the math to calculate.

..or can I convert the value to another variable in the first function that I can pass to the second?

Comment: "Can I pass “this” as a parameter to another function in javascript" --- yes you can, it is an ordinary variable with a reference to current object. Any issues with that?

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: `$($(this))` should just be `$(this)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The javascript functions `call()` and `apply()` are both for precisely for the purpose of calling a function within a context.

```
function sum() { 
    return this.num1 + this.num2; 
} 

function callSum(num1, num2) { 
    this.num1 = num1
    this.num2 = num2
    return sum.call(this);       //call sum() in the context of this 
} 

alert(callSum(10, 15)); 

function applySum(num1, num2) { 
    this.num1 = num1
    this.num2 = num2
    return sum.apply(this);   //call sum() in the context of this 
} 

alert(applySum(30, 45));
```

[jsfiddle example link](http://jsfiddle.net/FunkyFresh84/rFdrS/)

Now in the `sum()` function the `this` keyword had the same context as it does in the `callSum()` and `applySum()` functions.

The difference between `call()` and `apply()` is that apply's second parameter is either an array of parameters to pass or an `arguments` object.

Comment: what I thought the issue was, was that since the + is both an numerical operator and a string concantenation, the moment I try to add the variable holding "this" with another variable, the result is a new string....I need to parse the index value to keep it a number I think.... thanks to all, I need to go over all this and I'll mark the appropriate response.

Comment: Sure no worries. Remember though other people will be searching the title of the question asked so it's most beneficial to them if you mark an answer that answers the question in the title. If in the future you do need to call a method within a certain context these are the methods that the javascript language provides.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass `this` to another function like so:

```js
moveToNextImage(this, stepClicked);

function moveToNextImage(obj, stepClicked) {
   var index = $(obj).index;
}
```

In your code, what does this line mean:

```js
$($(this)).addClass('cs_current');
```

It should be:

```js
$(this).addClass('cs_current');
```

Comment: yes, correct... I was trying other things w/index and values..this should just be $(this)...kj