# JavaScript "This" is out of context, refers to window instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, self

I've got a situation where one function is calling another function changing the context of "this" being used. In the "check" function I've added in the variable 'self' to try to compensate for this, as well as the "alert" to make sure that "self" is displaying [object Object] (it is), but when I pass "self" to the "recurse" function, using an alert I can see that key becomes [object Window] and val becomes undefined. I can't for the life of me figure out how to solve this issue...

```
$.each(data, check);

function check(key, val){
    var self = this;
    if (self.group == "whatever"){
        alert(self);
        recurse(self);
    }
}

function recurse(key, val) {
    if (val instanceof Object) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty('subNav')) {
            items.push("<li class='" + this.n_class + "'><a target='" + this.target + "' href='" + this.link + "'>" + this.name + "</a>");
            items.push("<ul>");
            $.each(this.subNav, recurse);
            items.push("</ul></li>");
        }
        else {
            items.push("<li class='" + this.n_class + "'><a target='" + this.target + "' href='" + this.link + "'>" + this.name + "</a></li>");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Why does this code only pass one argument to `recurse`?

Comment: You're better off using `console.log()` rather than `alert()` so you can see what the object actually IS.

Comment: Why are you passing an instance of this, and not just key,val?

Comment: The issue is your use of `this` within the `recurse` function.

Comment: Where are the properties used with this located?

Comment: So what do you expect `this` to be within `recurse`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just needed "this" to refer to the same object so I removed the "key" and "val" parameters from recurse() and changed the val inside to "this", as well is called recurse inside check() using "recurse.call(this)" **(*see below)**

```
$.each(data, check);
function check(key, val){
    if (this.group == "whatever"){
        recurse.call(this); //*****first change
    }
}

function recurse() { //****removed parameters
    if (this instanceof Object) { //**** changed "val" to "this"
        if (this.hasOwnProperty('subNav')) {
            items.push("<li class='" + this.n_class + "'><a target='" + this.target + "' href='" + this.link + "'>" + this.name + "</a>");
            items.push("<ul>");
            $.each(this.subNav, recurse);
            items.push("</ul></li>");
        }
        else {
            items.push("<li class='" + this.n_class + "'><a target='" + this.target + "' href='" + this.link + "'>" + this.name + "</a></li>");
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript functions `call` or `apply`. For more info see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9812721/909535

```
recurse.call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Your using the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).
Within your function `this` will reference the global object by default; in the browser this is `window`.

I've modified your code slightly to fix your issue but it is not tested.

```
$.each(data, parse);

function parse(key, val) {
    if (val instanceof Object) {
    items.push("<li class='" + val.n_class + "'><a target='" + val.target + "' href='" + val.link + "'>" + val.name + "</a>");
        if (val.hasOwnProperty('subNav')) {
            items.push("<ul>");
            $.each(val.subNav, parse);
            items.push("</ul>");
        }
    items.push("</li>");
    }
};
```