# What to use - Passing context or call/apply?

Tags: javascript, this, call, apply, executioncontext

In javascript, If I have to invoke a function in a different context, what is the preferred way to invoke the same. and why?

1) Pass `this` as a parameter like below:

```
callthisfunction(arg1, arg2, this);
function callthisfunction(arg1, arg2, context) {}
```

OR

2) Make use of call/apply like given below:

```
callthisfunction.call(this, arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: Depends on the implementation of the function, if you are using `this` context in the function, then use `Function#call`, if you are using parameter name then use it as parameter...

Comment: Will your function ever be [partially applied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application)?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how the function works. If you are refering to the context by `this`, I would prefer the `call`.
You can use `context`, if you want to work with let's say the current and the passed scope.

You should maybe also take a look at this [article](http://hangar.runway7.net/javascript/difference-call-apply). It describes `call` a little bit more in detail. Also apply might be useful for you in the future.

EDIT: Also take a look at this [answer and the provided example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812445/can-i-pass-this-as-a-parameter-to-another-function-in-javascript).

Comment: you could have raised a flag for duplicate

Comment: @Mahi — Dupe of what ?

Comment: *"and the passed scope"* - `this` isn't about scope.

Comment: @nnnnnn Even if it is a parameter, when it get's passed as scope from another function, it is still a scope. In any case it would be an object passed as param. Just from the methodical point of view it would still be a scope.